# Choosing the best Time Series Decompositions technique for International Trade

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, arima, autoregressive, macroeconomics

I have monthly Export and Import of country by product groups and partners (countries). I want to analyze time series and decompose it into Trend, Seasonality and Remainder components.

My question is, according to your opinion, which may be the best choice to use:

[X11 decomposition](https://otexts.com/fpp2/x11.html)

[SEATS decomposition](https://otexts.com/fpp2/seats.html)

[STL decomposition](https://otexts.com/fpp2/stl.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these are well-established methods. If one of them were clearly superior across a wide range of datasets, it would have superseded the others. Thus, which one performs best will depend on your particular data. You could look at the Dagum & Bianconcini (2016) reference noted at the bottom of the linked pages.